Auth via Instagram
Could you please help me resolve the "Sorry, this content isn't available right now" issue with Instagram OAuth?

I created an app and obtained client_id & client_secret.
On the front-end, I implemented the redirect:

const myUrlWithParams = new URL('https://api.instagram.com/oauth/authorize')
myUrlWithParams.searchParams.append('client_id', '111')
myUrlWithParams.searchParams.append('redirect_uri', 'https://example.com/auth/instagram/')
myUrlWithParams.searchParams.append('scope', 'user_profile')
myUrlWithParams.searchParams.append('response_type', 'code')

window.location.href = myUrlWithParams.href


On the back-end, I set up a handler for /auth/instagram/:

# Getting access_token
request_data = {
    "client_id": "111",
    "client_secret": "222",
    "grant_type": "authorization_code",
    "code": request.GET.get("code"),
    "scope": "user_profile",
    "redirect_uri": "https://example.com/auth/instagram/",
}
response = requests.post("https://api.instagram.com/oauth/access_token", data=request_data, proxies=proxies)
access_token = response.json().access_token

# Requesting the user profile
response = requests.get("https://graph.instagram.com/me", data={"access_token": access_token, "fields": "username"})
print(response.text)  # "Sorry, this content isn't available right now"


The access_token is obtained correctly, and the app is active in https://www.instagram.com/accounts/manage_access/.
However, when I make a request to https://graph.instagram.com/me, I get the error "Sorry, this content isn't available right now" (I tried different versions like https://graph.instagram.com/v20.0/me).

Get fields and edges on a User
